# Running Parse function

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am having trouble with this [tutorial](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#command-line-installation/) from Parse.com. I have followed the steps all the way down to **A Simple Function**. I have deployed the code from my machine to the Parse Cloud but I am stuck on the part where it says:

> To run this function once it's deployed, run:

```
Parse.Cloud.run('hello', {}, {
  success: function(result) {
    // result is 'Hello world!'
  },
  error: function(error) {
  }
});
```

Where do I place this code? Does it go in cloud/main.js? Then do I just run the following code in terminal or do I actually add my **Application ID** and **Rest API Key** before I do?

```
curl -X POST \
 -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
 -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -d '{}' \
 https://api.parse.com/1/functions/hello
```

Comment: What does `Parse.Cloud.define('hello', function(request, response){....})` look like? The function `Parse.Cloud.run('hello'....` should have a corresponding define that has been deployed. Also there is a nice plugin I like to use instead of curl called ["postman"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) if you are using chrome.

Answer (score 0):

> Following ancient tradition, let's see how to run the simplest
>   possible function in the cloud. If you take a look at cloud/main.js,
>   you'll see an example function that just returns a string:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {
  response.success("Hello world!");
});
```

Inside of an html file, once you have have the above deployed you would:

```
<script src="//www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    Parse.initialize("APPLICATION ID", "JAVASCRIPT KEY");
    Parse.Cloud.run('hello', {}, {
        success: function(result) {
           // result is 'Hello world!'
           debugger;
        },
        error: function(error) {
        }
    });

</script>
```

As seen here: https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/web/existing

And in terminal if you are going to use `curl` you would:

```
APPLICATION_ID="yourapplicationid"
REST_API_KEY="yourrestapikey"
```

Comment: The `curl` stuff? Or the javascript?

Comment: It would go inside of an html file, or you could run it on nodejs, or you could copy and paste the minified www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.6.4.min.js file into console and then copy and paste the other script stuff into console?